# View the last image uploaded to the database using php

Tags: php

I am new in php and I am trying to view the last image uploaded to the database using php.
insertion code running perfectly but the selection one accrued an issue.

here is my code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['UploadImage'])) {
$image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
if ($image == '') {
    echo "<script> alert('please choose picture') </script>";
} else if ($image_type != "image/jpeg" && $image_type != "image/png" && $image_type != "image/gif") {
    echo "<script> alert('image format is not correct ') </script>";
} else {

    $query = "INSERT INTO  image (ImageLink) VALUES ('" . $image . "')";
    if (mysqli_query($db1, $query)) {
        echo '<script> alert("image uploaded successfully") </script>';
    } else {
        echo '<script> alert("please try again") </script>';
    }
}

if (mysqli_affected_rows($db1) > 0) {
    $query_image = "SELECT ImageLink FROM image ORDER BY Image_Id DESC LIMIT 1;";
    $result = mysqli_query($db1, $query_image);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<img width='450' height='600' src='data:image/jpeg; base64,".base64_encode($row['ImageLink'])."' >";
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
}?>
```

while running... image doesn't appear in page. 
please any help in doing that...
thank you

Comment: you didn't uploaded file to any folder? you directly save the temp file path in db? It won't work. Save image to some folder and add that folder path to db row .

Comment: Please do `var_dump( $row );` inside your `while` loop and post the results.

Comment: @AlivetoDie yes I directly save it to the db

Comment: @jrswgtr the result >>  array(1) { ["Image_Id"]=> string(2) "29" }

Comment: Allright, so `$row['ImageLink']` is not defined. That's one!

Comment: I suggest you read this page carefully: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: @jrswgtr thanks for helping me. `$row['ImageLink']` is not defined so I should save it to directory and then save the path to the db??? I didn't get that very well!

Comment: Yes, that would be the way to go!

Comment: @jrswgtr I am trying doing that.... it's giving me 2 errors for file name...  Undefined index: image for the file name `$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);` and  Undefined index: image in `if ($_FILES["image"]["size"] > 500000)`

Comment: To see what properties are available, do `var_dump( $_FILES['image'] );`.

Comment: @jrswgtr Undefined index: image on line 647 ..... NULL

Comment: That means the image is not successfully posted to your script. What is the `name` attribute of your file input? it should look like: `<input type="file" name="image" />`.

Comment: @jrswgtr yes input has `name`  attribute .. I have noticed the problem ,OK, error solved thank you ,, but the same issue to view the image accrued again even after upload the path into database :(

Comment: You don't need to use `base64`. You should display the image like this `'<img src="http://yourbaseurl.com/' 
 . $yourImagePath . '" />'`.

Comment: if you want to use `base64` it should be like this: `"<img src='data:image/jpeg; base64,".base64_encode(file_get_contents($row['ImageLink']))."' >"`

Comment: @jrswgtr  I didn't understand the first method you recommended  `<img src="http://yourbaseurl.com/' . $yourImagePath . '" />` ,, and I tried the second one `"<img src='data:image/jpeg; base64,".base64_encode(file_get_contents($row['ImageLink']))."' >"`  the same issue to view the image accrued again :(

Comment: The `src` attribute of the `<img>` tag should represent the url to the image on your server like this: `http://yoursite.com/uploads/yourimage.jpg`

Comment: @jrswgtr it finally worked THANKS

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. My pleasure! It would be nice if you posted your solution as an answer to your own question. That way it can help other people with the same problem

Comment: @jrswgtr OK, Thanks again :D

Answer (score 1):

Solution is:
HTML code

```
<table
            style="border-style: solid; border-color: gray; margin-top: 17px; width: 100%; height: 50%; width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <td>please upload a picture :</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="image" id="image"></td>

            </tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="UploadImage"
                    id="UploadImage"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["UploadImage"])){
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if (isset($_POST["UploadImage"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
        if ($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }
    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["image"]["size"] > 500000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif") {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
        // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file " . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]) . " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }

        $query = "INSERT INTO  image (ImageLink) VALUES ('" . $target_file . "')";
        if (mysqli_query($db1, $query)) {
            echo '<script> alert("Image Has been Uploaded Successfully") </script>';
        } else {
            echo '<script> alert("Please Try Again") </script>';
        }

        if (mysqli_affected_rows($db1) > 0) {
            $query_image = "SELECT ImageLink FROM image ORDER BY Image_Id DESC LIMIT 1;";
            $result = mysqli_query($db1, $query_image);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                // var_dump( $row );
                echo "<img width='450' height='600' src='data:image/jpeg; base64,".base64_encode(file_get_contents($row['ImageLink']))."'>";
                echo "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```